# 403.7 Forbidden using Client-Certificate Authentication in an Owin Self-Hosted Web API 2

Tags: authentication, ssl, asp.net-web-api, client-certificates, owin

Long time reader, first time poster.

### Goal:

We want to create an Owin Self-Hosted Web API 2 service that uses client certificates exclusively for authentication purposes.  The data services tier will be ran on the same machine as the client tier for development purposes.

### Environment/Configuration:

- The Web API 2 data service has been created.

  There is nothing complex about the service.  It does use a DelegatingHandler to verify the client certificate.
- The Web API 2 service has been "deployed" via four different
  scenarios:

  - IIS Express

    This deployment mode has been properly configured.  A SSL certificate is being used and the security is set to `<access sslFlags="Ssl, SslRequireCert"/>`.
  - IIS 

    This mode has also been properly configured with the SSL certificate  and requires client certificates set thru IIS Manager.
  - "Legacy" Web API 2 self-hosted console app 

    The SSL Cert has been properly bound to the port via netsh with the setting of "clientcertnegotiation=true".

    The configuration has set the ClientCredentialType to Certificate.
  - OWIN Web API 2 self-hosted console app

    The SSL Cert has been properly bound to the port via netsh with the setting of `clientcertnegotiation=true`.
- The client app is a WPF application.

  For the service call, we are using HTTPClient.
  The order of operations are:

  ```
      WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
      handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
      handler.ClientCertificates.Add(MyCertificates.OfType<X509Certificate2>).FirstOrDefault(cert => cert.Thumbprint == SelectedCertificateThumbprint) as X509Certificate2);
      handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
      client.BaseAddress = SetServiceBaseAddress(client);
      var results = client.PostAsync(<RequestURI>, <RequestDTO>, mediaTypeFormatter).Result;
  ```

### Constraints:

We are not authorized to install Wireshark or any other network monitoring tool onto these machines.

### Behavior:

- When using Fiddler to proxy to the IIS Express and IIS hosted data
  services:

  1. Fiddler will prompt a certificate warning due to a name mismatch for SSL (we haven't turned this off or generated one for localhost.fiddler).
  2. Fiddler will prompt for a "Request For Permission to Use a Key".  We believe this is a request to access the .pfx stored in Current User\Personal store based on the certificate (.cer) that is stored in the Fiddler directory so that Fiddler sign the request with the proper private key.
  3. After entering the proper password, the request succeeds.
- When using Fiddler to proxy to either the Owin or "Legacy" self-hosted data services:

  1. Fiddler will  prompt a certificate warning due to a name mismatch for SSL (we haven't turned this off or generated one for localhost.fiddler).
  2. A 403.7 - Forbidden is received immediately.
- When using all four hosting models without Fiddler to proxy:

  1. A successful response is received.

### Assumptions:

1. There seems to be a behavioral difference between the "SslRequireCert" setting in IIS and IISExpress and the self-hosted solution of "ClientCertNegotiate".
2. The client cert negotiation is properly working in the self-hosted solution due to  the fact that we are properly receiving the cert without using  Fiddler (we can intercept it in the debugger properly).
3. The behavioral differences between using Fiddler or not to proxy through appear to be related to a lower layer than what we can currently see.  We are attributing this right now to the TCP handshake.

### Questions:

1. Would the SSL certificate name mismatch have any bearing in the client-certificate forbidden problem?
2. In a self-hosting scenario, how do you specify the difference between "SslNegotiateCert" and "SslRequireCert"?
3. Is there a specific way within the OWIN hosting model to require client certificates?
4. Are we overlooking a specific configuration or setting in configuring the data service to behave the same way between an IIS-hosted solution and a self-hosted solution?
5. Is it possible that our errors are elsewhere, like in the client or Fiddler certificate configuration?

Answer (score 2):

I was just busy with a similar issue and I think I occasionally found an answer to your 2-nd question.

It's all about the way you bind your server cert to the port with netsh tool.

When setting **clientnegotiation** parameter to **enabled**, like this:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=<cert_thumbprint> appid={some_guid} clientcertnegotiation=enable
```

, the OWIN host starts requiring the client to provide some kind of client cert (it can be just any kind of cert).

When setting that parameter to **disable** or just omitting it, the OWIN host doesn't require anything from the client.